# I can't import pyarrow

Tags: python, pyarrow

when I am trying to import pyarrow in python, I get the following error:

```
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/services/matejm/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyarrow/_init_.py", line 49, in <module>
from pyarrow.lib import cpu_count, set_cpu_count
ImportError: libaws-cpp-sdk-s3.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

What can this be related to? I have searched wherever i could've and could not find any reason for it, so I figured i might as well try in here.

Thank you very much

Note: I have installed py-arrow and its dependencies off-line, since our cluster has a company firewall that does not allow pip installation

Comment: Can you share your OS details ?

Answer (score 1):

Is fixed now.

There had been some transient dependencies missing on the cluster that I was trying run it. (One of them was **aws-sdk-cpp**) python package